# How to check which cookies are sent on Alamofire request?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, httpcookie

I am using Alamofire for API requests. I need to check which cookies are sent on request.

```
NetworkService.configuration.httpCookieStorage?.setCookies(cookies, for: try url.asURL(), mainDocumentURL: nil)
```

I use this for set cookies but i can't see if it is set or not. Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code to find

```
let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: URL)
print(cookies)
```

## OR

You can use this(View all cookies).

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But, is this guaranteed that, this cookies will be sent with API request? Cause when I get the headers with `headerFields = response.request?.allHeaderField` it gives zero values.

Comment: Yes, I am damn sure and make sure cookies are enabled in alamofire

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies
```